# How to pass PHP variables to Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I found this way to send variables from PHP to Javascript.

Inside the `template.tpl.php` file, I have the following code.

```
<?php 
  echo '<div class="drupal-vars" style="display:none;">'.json_encode($variables).'</div>';
?>
```

Within Javascript, I have the following code:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() { 
      var variables = jQuery.parseJSON($('.drupal-vars').html()); 
      //Remove if youwant to clean the code.
      $('.drupal-vars').remove();
  });

}(jQuery));
```

I found another [solution](http://web.archive.org/web/20120429045346/http://ericlondon.com/passing-php-variables-javascriptjquery-and-debugging-firebug), but it's more complicated, although it may be better architectured.

1. Is there a better way to do it?
2. How ugly is what I am doing here?

---

The tutorial goes like:

> I'll start by creating a hook_menu() implementation to establish a
>   page callback:
>
> ```
> <?php
> function helper_menu() {
>
>   $items = array();
>
>   $items['js-vars'] = array(
>     'title' => t('Javascript Variables'),
>     'description' => t('Javascript Variables'),
>     'page callback' => 'helper_page_callback_js_vars',
>     'access arguments' => array('access content'),
>     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,    
>   );
>
>   return $items;
>
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> Next, I'll define the page callback:
>
> ```
> <?php
> function helper_page_callback_js_vars() {
>
>   // include module javascript file
>   drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','helper') . '/js/helper.js');
>
>   // define variables you'd like to pass to the DOM
>   $js_vars = array(
>     'js_vars' => array(
>       'message' => t('Hello @username', array('@username' => $GLOBALS['user']->name)),
>       'an_array' => array(
>         'color' => t('red'),
>         'name' => t('Eric'),
>       ),
>     ),
>   );
>
>   // pass variables to javascript
>   drupal_add_js($js_vars, 'setting');
>
>   // generate some page output
>   return "TEST";
>
> }
> ?>
> ```
>
> And here is the contents of the javascript include file I stuck in my
>   module directory:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>
>   // debug variables directly in FireBug
>   console.debug(Drupal.settings.js_vars);
>
>   // popup mesage passed from Drupal
>   alert(Drupal.settings.js_vars.message);
>
> });
> ```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'd be better off using [`drupal_add_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) to pass your object in the JS `Drupal.settings` object:

```
// In PHP:
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('variables' => $variables)), 'setting');

// In JS
var variables = Drupal.settings.myModule.variables;
```

Drupal handles all the conversions of objects/arrays internally and this is just a much cleaner way of doing it...at the moment you're including raw JSON as part of the page output which isn't great in terms of semantics; also bear in mind that search engines will pick up this text even though you're hiding it for users with javascript.

I'd also recommend separating this logic out from the template file itself and put it in a `template_preprocess_` function in your theme's `template.php` file...again it's just cleaner. e.g.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  $variables = $your_variables;
  drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('variables' => $variables)), 'setting');
}
```

Have a look at the link to the `drupal_add_js()` function, there are quite a lot of options and you'll probably find them quite useful.

Comment: I presume the javascript file also need to be referenced?

Comment: @AndrewWelch Yes, whatever file you're consuming `Drupal.settings.myModule` from will also need to be included explicitly

Answer (score 1):

Also, in other cases, you can use [drupal_to_js](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_to_js/6) function. It Converts a PHP variable into its Javascript equivalent.

```
<?php
  $php_settings = array(
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
  );
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var phpSettings = <?php echo drupal_to_js($php_settings); ?>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

an example on how to convert node datas to a js object:

in template.php

```
function mythemename_preprocess_node(&$variables){  
     drupal_add_js(array('node' => $variables['node']), 'setting');
}
```

in the page.tpl.php

```
  var node = Drupal.settings.node; 
 // console.log(node);
```