# Domain and URL variables

Tags: javascript

I have inherited some bad code in a Drupal 7.x site and it needs to be cleaned up.  Several places in the code the URL is hard-coded and I want to change that.  For example, in many of my javascript (.js) files I have something like this:

```
var url= 'http://dev3.ws.mysite.com/index.php/api/alerts_mix/x-api-key/blahhhhhhhhhzBkfqPTq4SWuCiLONePNfschNft';
```

In the PHP code I have the following:

```
     $url="http://dev3.ws.mysite.com/api/checkin/x-api-key/blahhhhhhhhhuRCMIWM0Nw0rM2cDK7tTJTPW?uid=11&lt="
```

First question...is it OK to have the entire URL for the API (including the key) hard-coded or should we be calling this some other way?

Second...for both the js and PHP, what can I use in place of the HTTP and domain (http://dev3.ws.mysite.com) so it is a variable and gets those values from the config files so I don't need to change this every time when making a new dev site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you add it in your custom module in [hook_init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468881/print-div-id-printarea-div-only) then it will exist everywhere,

```
function yourmodule_init(){
     $url="http://dev3.ws.mysite.com/api/checkin/x-api-key/blahhhhhhhhhuRCMIWM0Nw0rM2cDK7tTJTPW?uid=11&lt="
    drupal_add_js(array('yourmodule' => array('myurl' => $url)), array('type' => 'setting'));
    variable_set('myurl',$url);

}
```

Then in modules you can get it with

```
$url=variable_get('myurl');
```

and in JS files

```
var url=Drupal.settings.yourmodule.myurl;
```

Comment: I like this solution but am getting an error in js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined.  Were you able to get this solution working?

Comment: @Ryan sure, tell me where are you use it? come code here

Comment: Here is what I implemented in my custombootstrap.module file:

function yourmodule_init(){
        $apiurl="http://dev.ws.mysite.com/api"
        drupal_add_js(array('yourmodule' => array('myurl' => $apiurl)), array('type' => 'setting'));
        variable_set('myurl',$apiurl);
}

I am using it like this in a .js file:

var apiurl = Drupal.settings.yourmodule.myurl+'l_users_gis/x-api-key/blahhhhhhhhhhhBkfqPTq4SWuCiLONePNfschNft';

Answer (score 0):

For configuration, like an API server URL, I'd suggest using Drupal variables. There are several ways to set the variable:

1. In the settings.php:

`$conf['api_server'] = 'http://example.com';`

2. With Drush:

`drush vset api_server 'http://example.com'`

3. Build an admin screen where you can set the value. (Probably overkill in this case.)

In your code where you need the URL, use [variable_get()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_get/7):

```
$url = variable_get('api_server');
```

To access the value in JavaScript see: [How to pass PHP variables to Javascript/jQuery?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21566/how-to-pass-php-variables-to-javascript-jquery)